# How to store user preferences in IdentityServer

Tags: .net-core, angular7, identityserver4

I need to understand how to approach a problem and after reading a lot of documentation I still haven't figured out.

**So I have the following:**

- An angular app.
- Identity Server 4
- A .NET core API

The user logins to the api by being redirected to identity server which returns the access token to be used by the Angular Application.

The angular application sends the token with each request to the api which in turn validates the token against Identity Server.

**Now the issue is:**

User needs to store the id of some property that will be used all over the application. But now when the user selects that ID (or changes to a different one), I need to be able to store that information in identity server (I suppose it should be a custom claim). The idea is that whatever client authenticates against Identity Server should have access to this ID.

I'm a bit lost here because I'm not sure If I'm approaching the problem the correct way.

I know that I can use IProfileService and set custom claims when a user logs in but the reason I'm lost here is because what I really want to do is to store the user preference and I'm not sure If I should have an endpoint for this and on which side (API or Identity Server).

Can anyone point me on the correct direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the id preference is at user level, then it should go into the user db where u store the user's details(like username and password).

If your identity server talks to another service (eg: UserAPI) to get this user details .

1. Update the preference in UserAPI from the angular app (using the same token but right claims) or
2. Let the angular app talk to ur API and let the API talk to the UserAPI using client credentials flow to update the preference.